# Node.JS readStream unexpectedly closes before writeStream

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to fetch PDF files from remote servers and pipe them right back to the requesting clients like below:

```
var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
writeStream.on('close', function () {
    console.log("Closed write stream");
});
writeStream.on('open', function () {
    console.log('Open event for writestream');
});
writeStream.on('pipe', function () {
    console.log('pipe event for writestream');
    var rd = fs.createReadStream(filename);
    rd.on('open', function () {
        console.log('Open event for readstream');
    });
    rd.on('close', function () {
        console.log("Closed read stream");
    }).pipe(res);
});
request(pQuestURL)
    .on('error', function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.json({ status: -1, message: 'Maps error, check your parameters' });
    })
    .pipe(writeStream);
```

But it gives me output like below:

```
pipe event for writestream
Open event for writestream
Open event for readstream
Closed read stream
Closed write stream
```

I was expecting the `readstream` to only finish after the `writestream` has finished. The `readstream` appears to close instantly and therefore my client receives an empty response while the writestream finishes only after downloading the whole pdf. Is there a hole in my understanding? How can I pipe right back without waiting for the `finish` event of the `writestream`?

**Edit:**

Actually I can save the readable stream in a variable and pipe it to as many writable streams as I want. I accomplished my goal by simplifying the as:

```
var mapRequest = request(pQuestURL);
mapRequest.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.json({ status: -1, message: 'Maps error, check your parameters' });
});
mapRequest.pipe(writeStream);
mapRequest.pipe(res);
```

Comment: why do you need a writeStream? Cant you just request(pQuestURL).pipe(res); ??? Looks like your readStream is faster as the writeStream, as the writeStream is dependend on the download speed...

Comment: You're right. I can save the readable stream in a variable and pipe it to as many writables as I want. Editing my question now. Thanks

Comment: and theres no need to store the file on your server. it will just waste ressources...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that the readStream is faster as the writeStream is dependend on the download speed. So you either stream to the user directly:

```
 request(pQuestURL).pipe(res);
```

Alternatively you could wait for the writeStreams data event, and retrieve a chunk of the writeStream. However this is unneccessary in my opinion...